# How is this possible?

Tags: integration

Today, at a physics lecture there was a problem:

$a = 20x + 5$ where a was the accelerationas a function of position($x$) and we were to solve for velocity.

The professor did the following:
$dv/dt = 20x + 5$ so far, fine. Then he **multiplied the LHS by $dx/dx$**
$=> dx/dx * dv/dt = 20x + 5$
$=> v dv = 20x+ 5 dx$ and then integrated both sides to solve for velocity. This makes no sense to me. How is it possible to just multiply by $dx/dx$?

Many times when we do things like:
$dx/dt = 2x$ and "multiply" both sides by dt and integrate, we're really just integrating both sides with respect to $t$ and the aforementioned multiplication is just a shorthand way of doing this.

In this case what are we really doing here when we're multiplying by $dx/dx$ and what would be the "correct" way of solving for $v$ here?

Comment: The multiplying by $\frac{dx}{dx}$ is technically chain rule.

Comment: $\dfrac{dx}{dx}$ is the derivative of $x$ with respect to $x$ which is 1.  This is just a sneaky to to use the chain rule since he goes from $\dfrac{dx}{dx}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ to $\dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a (almost) pure-symbols proof.]

Given variables $x,v$ varying with respect to $t$ such that $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$:

If $\frac{dv}{dt} = 20x+5$:

$v \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dt} = 20x+5$.   [The chain rule here **requires** $\frac{dv}{dx}$ to exist.]

$\int v \frac{dv}{dx}\ dx = \int (20x+5)\ dx$.

$\int v\ dv = \int (20x+5)\ dx$.   [The change-of-variables here is valid if $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is continuous in $t$.]

Answer (score 1):

If
$$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=20x+5,$$
where
$$v=v(x(t)),$$
then the derivative of a composite function is of the form
$$\dfrac{dv}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=20x+5,$$
$$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=20x+5,$$
$$vdv=(20x+5)dx.$$

Comment: In the second last step, instead of multiplying both sides by $dx$, if I was to integrate with respect to $x$ how would that work out? $\int f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} \, dx = \int g(x) \, dx$ in this case $dy/dx$ is the derivative of the composite function inside $f(y)$ so substitution would work out but I don't know how it would work in $v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=20x+5$ considering $dv/dx$ isn't the derivative of the composite function of $v$

Comment: @xasthor The last step is the standard for equations with multiple variables. It is based on the differential invariant properties.

Comment: So is there no way to solve it if I integrate both sides of $v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=20x+5$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: @xasthor $\dfrac{dy}{dx}dx=dy$ as the differential of a composite function, so $\int f(y)\dfrac{dy}{dx}dx=\int f(y)dy$. And at the another case we will integrate with respect to $x$, because we have the differential of $x$

Comment: @$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}$ is a product of the acceleration and velocity, which are just two different functions

Comment: Yes, $\int f(y)\dfrac{dy}{dx}dx=\int f(y)dy$ this follows directly from the "reverse" chain rule since $y$ is the composite function in $f$. However, in $v(x)\dfrac{dv}{dx}=20x+5$ $dv/dx$ is the derivative of $v$ not its composite function $x$

Comment: @xasthor brackets must be, of course.